# How can I get unique words per each topic LDA?

Tags: python, gensim, cpu-word, lda

I am trying to get unique words for each topic.

I am using gensim and this is the line that help me to generate my model

```
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=2, id2word = dictionary)
```

But I have repeated words in two different topics, I would like to have different words per topic

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enforce words uniqueness by topic in LDA since each topic is a distribution over all the words in the vocabulary. This distribution measure the probability that words co-occur inside a topic. Thus, nothing ensures that a word won't co-occur with different words in different contexts, which will leads to words represented in different topics.

Let's take an example by considering these two documents:

- doc1: The python is a beautiful snake living in the forest.
- doc2: Python is a beautiful language used by programmer and data scientist.

In doc1 the word `python` co-occur with `snake`, `forest` and `living` which might give a good probability for this word to appear in a topic, let's say, about **biology**.

In doc2, the word `python` co-occur with `language`, `programmer` and `data` which, in this case, will associate this word in a topic about **computer science**.

What you can eventually do, is to look for words that have the highest probability in topics in order to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Words that are grouped into one topic do not mean that they are semantically similar(low distance in space mapped from word2vec). They are just co-occurred more often.